# Change of wording on posts at Stack Apps

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, stackapps

Over at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/), the majority of the posts are either scripts to change/add features on the Stack Exchange network, or an app that you can download. Like every other Stack website, you have to "Ask a question" to post said scripts. I think that it is a little useless to say that the person who posted the script "Asked a question." I think that it would be a little more appropriate to say "Posted a Script/App." There could be a simple interface down where the "Post your question" button is. It could be set up as a radio interface

```
Are you posting a
  [] Question
  [] Script
  [] App
```

Then the button could be greyed out until the user selects one, or it could be defaulted as a question. Alternatively, the interface could be put right onto the button, in a sort of a dropdown style.

---

On the other hand, many of the "answers" that are posted on said apps/scripts are either bug reports or feature suggestions. There should be a similar interface for these answers.

```
Are you posting a
  [] Answer
  [] Feature Suggestion
  [] Bug
```

One script in particular that drew my attention to this issue is [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). This script has over 43 "answers," with most of them being feature suggestions. The OP was smart enough to edit in a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag for the ones he did implement. I think that there is a much more efficient way of doing this.

I think that for feature requests, there should be an option to "accept the answer," but instead of having the big green check mark, it would be a smaller, perhaps blue check mark. This could indicate that the feature has been implemented, and the OP is acknowledging the Feature Requester of his help. Instead of adding 15+ rep to the user, it could add a small amount, say 3+ rep. If the Feature Requester actually helped give code to implement the feature, there could be a third check mark, say yellow, that would be like an improved acknowledgement. This could award something like 6+ rep

Comment: I think the reason it's like is because questions about the API and things like that. You'd have to leave the questions part there for that.

Comment: @Seth That is why there would still be the option to post a question

Comment: Someone should write a script that changes the UI :-P

Answer (score 6):

I'm one of the moderators over at Stack Apps - I'll do my best to answer your questions.

> "StackApps doesn't have a meta site that I know of, so I posted this on here. Feel free to migrate it if you feel it would fit better on another site."

This is correct. The ["how to ask"](https://stackapps.com/questions/how-to-ask) page states that "If your question is about the site itself, ask on our meta-discussion site." (The link points here on Meta.)

> "On the other hand, many of the "answers" that are posted on said apps/scripts are either bug reports or feature suggestions."

Someone recently asked [a similar question](https://stackapps.com/questions/3974/should-feature-requests-for-third-party-apps-be-flagged-as-not-an-answer) about flagging "answers" to app posts requesting or suggesting new features. There is no official policy on this as far as I know. Personally, I have no problem with answers being used for this purpose since there really isn't any alternative available (at least not without resorting to a third-party service).

I actually created [a website](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com) at one point to try to alleviate the problem. Sadly, it never really took off.

> "I think that there is a much more efficient way of doing this."

I'm sure there is. It's important to remember that the Stack Exchange platform isn't really designed to be used as a bug / feature tracker. Although it is true that there are already quite a few features specific to Stack Apps (such as the thumbnails on the homepage), I doubt your changes could be easily implemented without a considerable amount of effort.

Instead, I would encourage the authors of some of the apps that receive a lot of feature requests to register with a third-party service (like [Trello](http://trello.com), for example). These sites provide a much easier way to track feature requests.

Comment: I think the OP's point was that "Question" and "Answer" are severe misnomers, not that they are ineffective at getting the point across.

Comment: So how do you feel about the questions part?

Answer (score 4):

There are tags though, like "script," which you can use. This is almost the same as meta, with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).

I don't think the familiar and *consistent-between-sites* format needs to be changed on Stack Apps or Meta.

For the "I completed this" on answers, the OP can always leave a comment or edit, as he did. There is not really a need for a whole new format.